# Material UI Tab overrides focused not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a react app and using Material UI as the styling library. It's working well but I can't turn a blue outline around a tab(button) component in my code (see image)

[image]

I can turn it off in the console using `button:focus { /* turning off outline props*/}`

But overriding the styles aren't working for me in the code, I've tried

```
  root: {
    
    ...

    "& .MuiButtonBase-root" : {
      "& button:focused" :{
        
          outline: "none"
        
    }}
```

Then

```
overrides: {
    "& .MuiButtonBase-root" : {
      "& button:focused" :{
        
          outline: "none"
        
    }}
  }
```

and overriding by applying a class to the component

```
buttonFocus: {

    outline: "none !important"
  }
```

clearly I'm doing something stupid. Please help.

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem. I don't think this outline is coming from Material-UI -- presumably you have some global styles that are causing this. Without knowing what those style rules look like, it is hard to help with how to successfully override them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone else has this issue, I added

```
  *:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

To my app.css file to override any style changes from Material UI. Thank you for your help and advice

Comment: except, don't do this. It breaks accessibility.

Comment: This is terrible for accessibility

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you have to use `primary` or `secondary` colors with material ui to set outline color.

Lets say you have your Button component:

```
<Button variant="outlined" color="primary">
   HOWELL DIBBERT
</Button>
```

As yo can see I use `variant="outlined"` to outline the button and then I set the color to `"primary"`. What does it means primary? Primary is the color I setted in my `Theme` like this:

```
export const Theme = {
    palette: {
        primary: {
            contrastText: '#FFFFFF',
            dark: '#0000FF',
            main: '#0000FF',
            light: '#0000FF',
        },
    }
};
```

And finally assing your theme to your app. In App.js file:

```
import { Theme } from 'path/to/your/Theme';
...
export default function App() {
   
   const theme = createMuiTheme(Theme);

   return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      ....
      </ThemeProvider>
   );
 }
```